# Electron inertia

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

As electron has a discrete mass it can't slow down immidiately, but what about its spin?When a magnetic field is applied does its spin change immediately making in that case a hughe electromagnetic signal due to fast change of magnetic flux in a differential of time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance - given the GHz range to interact with the spin flips, that tells you the energy required and thus limits on any electromagnetic signal you create.

Answer (score 1):

Electron spin - paramagnetic - resonance (EPR) typically involves frequencies of up to a few tens of GHz, that is in the microwave range. A quantum of this energy is absorbed or emitted. This process takes many periods and this is known as the relaxation time.

Answer (score 0):

The presupposition of the question is incorrect: it is not possible to apply magnetic field instantaneously. Any change in the field would have to happen through some non-zero period of time. Spin of electron will align with the field eventually, but not immediately either.

In any case, the emitted signal's energy would be bound by the energy difference between initial and final state which is, needless to say, for a single electron is proportional to $\hbar$ and thus is very small.